# ¿Es posible saltar a una dirección de memoria en inline assembly?

Tags: c, ensamblador, programación-bajo-nivel, filesystem

Estoy trabajando en un sistema operativo en C y ensamblador. Este cumple la especificación Multiboot, ya que se carga con GRUB.

He leído que GRUB tiene la capacidad de cargar módulos o initial ramdisks en memoria RAM para que el sistema operativo pueda usarlos y que este último obtiene la posición de memoria del módulo a través del parámetro `struct multiboot *mboot->mods_addr` de su función principal.

Trato de que el sistema de un salto a esa posición de memoria para poder ejecutar código máquina desde ahí y no puedo. No sé cuál podrá ser el problema. Cualquier ayuda es recibida.

El siguiente es mi código (muy reducido a las funciones relacionadas con el salto):

Entrada multiboot:

```
#define MULTIBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC 0x1BADB002
#define MULTIBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS 0x00000003
#define STACK_SIZE 0x4000

.text
.globl _start
_start:
    jmp multiboot_entry
    .align 4
multiboot_header:
    .long 0x1BADB002
    .long 0x00000003
    .long -(0x1BADB002+0x00000003)
multiboot_entry:
    movl $(stack + 0x4000), %esp
    call kernel_main
loop: hlt
    jmp loop
.section ".bss"
    .comm stack, 0x4000
```

Función `kernel_main()`:

```
#include <multiboot.h>
int kernel_main(struct multiboot *mboot)
{
    unsigned int location = *((unsigned int*)mboot->mods_addr);
    char* welcome = "Bienvenido a mi \"Sistema Operativo Sin Un Buen Nombre\" (S.O.S.U.B.N)!";
    char* content = (char*)location;
    clear();
    prints(welcome);
    jmpto(location);
    return 0;
}
```

Función `jmpto()`:

```
int jmpto(unsigned int jmplocation)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__("jmp %0" : : "r"(jmplocation));
    return 0;
}
```

Archivo multiboot.h:

```
#define MULTIBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC 0x1BADB002
#define MULTIBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS 0x00000003
#define MULTIBOOT_FLAG_MEM 0x001
#define MULTIBOOT_FLAG_DEVICE 0x002
#define MULTIBOOT_FLAG_CMDLINE 0x004
#define MULTIBOOT_FLAG_MODS 0x008
#define MULTIBOOT_FLAG_AOUT 0x010
#define MULTIBOOT_FLAG_ELF 0x020
#define MULTIBOOT_FLAG_MMAP 0x040
#define MULTIBOOT_FLAG_CONFIG 0x080
#define MULTIBOOT_FLAG_LOADER 0x100
#define MULTIBOOT_FLAG_APM 0x200
#define MULTIBOOT_FLAG_VBE 0x400
struct multiboot {
    unsigned int flags;
    unsigned int mem_lower;
    unsigned int mem_upper;
    unsigned int boot_device;
    unsigned int cmdline;
    unsigned int mods_count;
    unsigned int mods_addr;
    unsigned int num;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int addr;
    unsigned int shndx;
    unsigned int mmap_length;
    unsigned int mmap_addr;
    unsigned int drives_length;
    unsigned int drives_addr;
    unsigned int config_table;
    unsigned int boot_loader_name;
    unsigned int apm_table;
    unsigned int vbe_control_info;
    unsigned int vbe_mode_info;
    unsigned int vbe_mode;
    unsigned int vbe_interface_seg;
    unsigned int vbe_interface_off;
    unsigned int vbe_interface_len;
};
```